# Excel - Vlookup or Index Match with various criteria

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to fill in values under the "QTY" column of the Target sheet 2 (COL D), BY LOOKINGUP the values from the source sheet 1 (img 1). The quantities need to be referenced by 'Material' and 'Size'.

Img 1: Source Sheet 1 with Quantities corresponding to Sizes (highlighted in Yellow)
[image: Source Tab with Quantities Against Sizes]

Img 2: Target sheet 2 where I have to enter the Quantity values

[image]

Any help on the formula would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Never, ever use VLOOKUP for anything.  Ever.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$E$5,
MATCH(H5,$A$2:$A$5,0),
MATCH(I5,$B$1:$E$1,0))
```

Comment: You Sir! Saved so much of my time and I am ever so grateful! Thank you!!!!